# How to set the default Puppet environment to something other than production?

Tags: puppet

I did search, but didn't find exactly what I'm looking for.  In the past, I've had multiple Puppet masters, one for each environment, then made scripts to promote code from one environment to the next on a monthly basis, but that process is a pain.  I'm currently working on a single Puppet Master and am trying to take advantage of the environments feature but don't want the default environment set to production.  This should be simple, but I've not yet worked out the solution.  Without needing to set environments in the agents, how do I set the default environment on the master to "quarantine"?  I'm running puppetserver 7.9.2.1 on Oracle Linux 8.

Answer (score 0):

> Without needing to set environments in the agents, how do I set the default environment on the master to "quarantine"?

This is the [`environment`](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/configuration.html#environment) setting in the main `puppet.conf` configuration file.  For `[agent]` configuration it specifies which environment the agent should request (which is not necessarily the one it gets), but for `[server]` configuration it specifies the default environment assigned when the agent does not request one and none is provided by the node terminus.

Example:

```
# ...

[server]
environment = quarantine
# ...
```

Because it has different significance to different Puppet components, you should avoid specifying this setting in the `[main]` section.  You can meaningfully specify different values for this setting in different sections.

---

Although that answers what you actually asked, it might not be what you really want.  Note well that the default environment set at the server will be overridden if a client requests a specific environment.  If you want to prevent your Puppet clients from (successfully) specifying their own environments then you will want to set up an [external node classifier](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/nodes_external.html#external-node-classifiers) that specifies at least the environment for each node.  And if you have that, then whatever default you set in `puppet.conf` will be moot.